# Mapping route from root url to dynamic product title / id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm developing an MVC 3 app

I want to have a url something like:

/some-product-name-goes-here-4726482648
(with 4726482648 being the product id)

I do have other pages such as:

/category-name
(allows browsing by category)

/about

etc...

How could I go about setting up routing to allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would certainly be using a RouteConstraint here

in your routes you could have something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("CustomProductUrl",
                 "{Product}",
                 new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" },
                 new { Product= new ProductConstraint() }
                );
```

then in your ProductConstraint class you would have something as follows:

```
    public class ProductConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {

        public ProductConstraint ()
        {
        }

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            //do your logic in here to split the name and the id and amke sure it is valid data

            //if valid return true;
            //else false;
        }

    }
```

lastly in the Method signature of the Index action (or action in the route) take the string of the - and then split it down and process as appropriate

let me know if there are any issues

paul

Comment: yeah routes are executed in order so this is a more specific one and would need to appear further up the list

Answer (score 1):

If you can make them slightly different this would be very simple. For example, if you can use the following URL structure:

```
/some-product-name-goes-here/4726482648 (notice the slash)
/category-name
/about
```

The following routes would do the trick:

```
routes.MapRoute("about", "about", ... )
routes.MapRoute("product", "{product}/{id}", ... )
routes.MapRoute("category", "{category}", ... )
```

Comment: thanks... i've looked at doing this, but id really like to be able to keep the url hyphen separated... maybe some kind of regex would do the trick?

Comment: Yeah, you certainly can add constrains to your routes and handle it like that but it might get messy. But if that is a requirement then it might be your best bet.